# Can blender game engine detect if a character is falling and play an animation?

Tags: game-engine

so I have a character in bge and I want to play an animation of him falling when he falls. I've tried using a collision sensor and enabling invert, but whenever the character jumps, it plays that animation, instead of the jump animation. I also have an always sensor connected to the idle animation, and the game engine just plays that instead of the fall animation. 
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
Is it possible to detect the velocity of the character and play the fall animation when greater than a certain value?

Comment: You could check its position on the z axis and compare it to a stored value that changes when he climbs or descends normally. If the position is less than the stored value, you play the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KX_GameObject.worldLinearVelocity](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldLinearVelocity)

On a Physics object the Z-axis of the coordinates would be negative.

As static objects do to move (via Physics engine) this attribute will remain (0,0,0). This will be the case on physics types *Static*, *Occluder*, *Sensor*, *Navigation Mesh*, *Character*. This is a bit strange as this types (except *Static*) have not really much to do with physics (it is more a purpose type). Changes in location (which is basically a teleportation), can only be tracked by recording the previous position and comparing it to the current one.

Here is an example:

```
import bge

PROPERTY_LAST_POSITION = "last.position"

gameObject = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
currentPosition = gameObject.worldPosition
lastPosition = gameObject.get(PROPERTY_LAST_POSITION, currentPosition)
gameObject[PROPERTY_LAST_POSITION] = currentPosition.copy()
positionDifference = currentPosition - lastPosition

isFalling = (positionDifference.z < 0)

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
for actuator in controller.actuators:
    if isFalling:
        controller.activate(actuator)
    else:
        controller.deactivate(actuator)
```